# Get Pages of Created PDF Documents

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I created a List filled with documents I created with HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.
Now I want to create a new PDF with the combined pages of my documents in the list without saving all the documents to my hard drive.

The following code didn't work because pdfDocument wasn't opened in PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import. But to me, it looks like I can only do this by saving all documents to my hard drive and open them with PdfReader.Open().

```
private PdfDocument CombinePdfs(List<PdfDocument> pdfDocuments)
{
    PdfDocument combinedPdf = new PdfDocument();
    foreach (var pdfDocument in pdfDocuments)
    {
        foreach (PdfPage page in pdfDocument.Pages)
        {
            combinedPdf.AddPage(page);
        }
    }
    return combinedPdf;
}
```

Any clue how I could solve this?

**Edit:**

Following Code did work for me.

```
private PdfDocument CombinePdfs(List<PdfDocument> pdfDocuments)
{
    PdfDocument combinedPdf = new PdfDocument();
    foreach (var pdfDocument in pdfDocuments)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        pdfDocument.Save(stream, false);
        PdfDocument importDocument = PdfReader.Open(stream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

        foreach (PdfPage page in importDocument.Pages)
        {
            combinedPdf.AddPage(page);
        }
    }

    return combinedPdf;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the PDF documents to a `MemoryStream` and read them from there to avoid file I/O. At least you do not have the hassle with temporary files on your hard disk.